# Unable to called the Method of the Class in Dialog Class

Tags: android, class, methods, dialog

I have one Modal Class ::

```
public class A
{
    java.lang.String fieldName;
    java.lang.String fieldType;

    public static class B
    {
        java.lang.String  Min;
        java.lang.String Max;

        public java.lang.String getMin() {
            return Min;
        }
        public void setMin(java.lang.String string) {
            Min = string;
        }
        public java.lang.String getMax() {
            return Max;
        }
        public void setMax(java.lang.String string) {
            Max = string;
        }
    }

    public java.lang.String getFieldName() {
        return fieldName;
    }

    public void setFieldName(java.lang.String string) {
        this.fieldName = string;
    }

    public java.lang.String getFieldType() {
        return fieldType;
    }

    public void setFieldType(java.lang.String string) {
        this.fieldType = string;
    }
}
```

Now i want to called the Method of this class in another class which `extends Dialog`

i have tried a lot like

```
com.test.modal.A.B number=new A.B();
```

or

```
context.com.test.modal.A.B number=new A.B();
```

Here it is my **Dialog Class**

```
public class TestDialog extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener 
{

     //com.test.modal.A.B number=new A.B();
    com.test.modal.A.B number;

    public TestDialog (Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public TestDialog (Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        this.number=new Number.ValidationNumber();
    }
    String min=number.getMin();
}
```

I want to called the Method of Modal Class and need to fetch the values from it.
I am not able to get the values once i called the methods....

Any help will be appreciated !!!!

Thanks in Advance ....

Comment: your implementation is correct, this might another problem

Comment: any clue??? why m not getting the value of that class?

Comment: Where did you set the values? Can show the code